# iReport group totals not working

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I had a working version of an iReport version 4.1.3 which had the needed percentages, totals, averages and counts within text. The report and totals/calculations did work correctly for this report.  I needed another version that was exactly the same but within groups.  I edited the mysql to order by the group Territory, then added Report groups.  I then changed the Reset type to Group/Reset group to Territory.  I have also played around with changing the increment type also to Group/ and increment group to Territory also.  I am currently am getting a report with each database line creating a separate page rather than totals by territory.

Variable example:

```xml
<variable name="AverageAgeOver61" class="java.lang.Double" resetType="Group" resetGroup="Territory" incrementType="Group" incrementGroup="Territory">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$V{TotalAgeOvr61}.equals(0) ? 0 : $V{TotalAgeOvr61} / $V{CountOver61}]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
<variable name="DomantTotalAge" class="java.lang.Double" resetType="Group" resetGroup="Territory" incrementType="Group" incrementGroup="Territory" calculation="Sum">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{Dormant} ? $F{Age} : 0]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
<variable name="HighRiskPercentage" class="java.lang.Double" resetType="Group" resetGroup="Territory" incrementType="Group" incrementGroup="Territory">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$V{totalSystems}.equals(0) || $V{totalSystems}.equals(null) ? 0 : $V{HighRiskSystemTotal} / $V{totalSystems}]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
<variable name="SeviceContractRiskPercentage" class="java.lang.Double" resetType="Group" resetGroup="Territory" incrementType="Group" incrementGroup="Territory">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$V{HighRiskServiceTotal}.equals(0) || $V{HighRiskServiceTotal}.equals(null) ? 0:$V{HighRiskServiceTotal}/$V{CurrentServiceAmountTotal}]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
```

and Text field examples:

```xml
<group name="TerritoryById">
    <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{TerritoryId}]]></groupExpression>
    <groupHeader>
        <band height="150">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="2" y="106" width="520" height="23"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="18"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{ClientShort} + " Findings:\n"+
                "a.\t"+new java.text.DecimalFormat("#,##0%").format($V{HighRiskPercentage})   +"    of the systems are in the \"High Risk\" category \n"+
                "b.\t"+new java.text.DecimalFormat("#,##0%").format($V{SeviceContractRiskPercentage})+ "      of service contract revenue is in the \"High Risk\" category\n"+
                "c.\t The average age for all systems in " +new java.text.DecimalFormat("#,##0").format($V{AvgAgeOfSystems}) +   " months, with " +$V{PercentageOver3yrsOld}+  "   of the systems over three years old.\n"+
                "        i.\t" + new java.text.DecimalFormat("#,##0%").format($V{Percentage37To48})+ " -\t  37 to 48 months old,\t"    + $V{CountAge37To48Qty}  +   "  systems \n"+
                "        ii.\t " + new java.text.DecimalFormat("#,##0%").format($V{Percentage49To60})+ " -\t  49 to 60 months old,\t "+ $V{CountAge49To60Qty} + " systems \n"+
                "        iii.\t "  +  $V{Percentage61Months} + " \t  61+ months old,\t\t "    + $V{CountOver61Qty}  +   " systems\n"+
                "d.\t Domant Accounts:\t" +$P{ClientShort}+ " identifies account where there has not been any systems added to the service contract with in the last two years. While these accounts may have purchased upgrades, software and service the lack of system additions is of concern.  For your territory, "+ $V{DomantAccts} + " of " + $V{totalCustomers}
                + " accounts, may be dormant.  This accounts for " + new java.text.DecimalFormat("#,##0%").format($V{PercentageServiceRevenueDorm})+", "+ new java.text.DecimalFormat("\$#,##0.00").format($V{DomantServiceRevenue})+" of the service revenue and  " +new java.text.DecimalFormat("#,##0%").format($V{PercentDomantUnits})+", "+ new java.text.DecimalFormat("#,##0").format($V{DormantUnitsTotal}) + " of the units on service contracts."]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
```

and there is a subreport listing the top ten:
"e. The top ten service revenue customers account for  "+new java.text.DecimalFormat("#,##0%").format($V{PercentageTotal})+" a service revenue, with an average of "+new java.text.DecimalFormat("#,##0%").format($V{PercentageHighRisk})+" of the service revenue in the \"High Risk\" category."

Comment: And what is the expression of your variable and the `calculation` property? Can you post the snippet?

Comment: Example variables: <variable name="TotalDeals" class="java.lang.Integer" resetType="Group" resetGroup="Territory" incrementType="Group" incrementGroup="Territory" calculation="Sum">
  <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{Deals}.equals("")||$F{Deals}.equals(null)? 0:$F{Deals}]]></variableExpression>
 </variable>

Comment: <variable name="NewServiceAmount" class="java.lang.Float" resetType="Group" resetGroup="Territory" incrementType="Group" incrementGroup="Territory" calculation="Sum">
  <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{NewServiceAmt}.equals(null)? 0:$F{NewServiceAmt}]]></variableExpression>
 </variable>

Comment: <variable name="TotalNetSaleOppIsDomant" class="java.lang.Float" resetType="Group" resetGroup="Territory" incrementType="Group" incrementGroup="Territory" calculation="Sum">
  <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{Dormant} ? $F{NetPriceOfNewProduct}: 0]]></variableExpression>
 </variable>

Comment: There are many more, including averages, counts, etc.  Anything in particular I should look for?  I also have two calculations I need to revise - they are currently nulls.  Could that cause the problem.  You have to forgive me, I am a new junior developer.

Comment: You should edit your question to add in the details rather than posting them as comments. Also include a snippet of the Text Field Expression that you use in the group footer.

Comment: mdahlman, As requested, I have edited The details.  Sherry

Comment: Why did you use `incrementType="Group"` and `incrementGroup="Territory"`? Can you explain what do you want to achieve? The sample with data will be very helpful

Comment: That was just my playing around to try to find the answer.  I have since removed them.  Sherry

Comment: I also have a sub-report in the group, could that effect the grouping?

Comment: This report is for managers to access sales potential of clients.